# What is the best way to test Silverlight 5 Class libraries?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, tfs

important requirement: support running the tests in the Nightly Build of the TFS.

p.s - 
Those I know are NUnit, and Silverlight testing framework. don't know which of them is suitable or preferred for my needs.

Comment: Will the Silverlight 5 Class libraries contain UI? In other words: do you need UI automation to be executed?

Comment: @Erno - no I don't need UI automation

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150285/automated-silverlight-5-unit-testing-for-business-logic and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046770/automation-ui-testing-tool-for-silverlight-5

Answer (score 0):

NUNit will work for class libraries. Just create objects, call functions and use Assert functions to test if actual = expected.

Answer (score -1):

What is contained in the Silverlight libraries? One limiting solution is to convert them to Portable Class Libraries. These could then be referenced from ordinary Test projects.